# Cannot find word in txt dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt file with several thousand words. However, when I try and pull them into a `dictionary` variable in python 3.7 some words do not appear.

The dictionary file is [here](https://github.com/EML-student/Dictionary-)

For example:

```
dictionary = {}
with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = file.readline().strip()
        dictionary[line] = 0

if "eat" in dictionary:
    print("Yes")
```

Why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried doing `print(dictionary)` before the `if`, to verify whether it works properly? Maybe with a smaller `.txt` file to test?

Comment: Thanks. So I just worked out I need to remove the following line: ```line = file.readline().strip()```. I think the code was skipping every other line because I had the word ```file``` twice!

Comment: @EML no, it's because you **are calling readline**.

Answer (score 1):

try  with this code:

```
dictionary = {}
with open("en-dict.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as file:
    for line in file:
        dictionary[line.split("\n")[0]] = 0
print(dictionary)
if "eat" in dictionary:
    print("Yes")
```

Comment: Thank you. I realised that I was skipping every other line by saying ```for line in file``` and then ```line=file```. Of course file is a generator object! Silly me. Thanks for your help

Comment: @EML no, `line = file` wouldn't matter, the problem is that you are calling `readline` while iterating over the file